# Неправильно удаляет элемент в listView(всегда последний) использую Loaders

Tags: java, android, listview

Я знаю, что есть немало вопросов по этой теме, я много из них просмотрел но никто из них не использовал Loaders API, я уже реализовал эту функцию в другом приложении и все работало, но в этом возникли проблемы и я зашел в тупик. Из базы удаляет правильно, а вот в ListView всегда удаляется только последний.

Я удаляю через контекстное меню, вот код:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.add(0, DELETE, 0, "Delete");
   /* tracker.setId(acmi.id);
    tracker.load(db);*/
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)
            item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case DELETE:
            RemindMe.db.delete(Tracker.TABLE_NAME, Tracker.COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(acmi.id)});
            Log.d("myTag", "acmi.id = " + acmi.id);
            elapsed.remove(acmi.position);
            break;
    }
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();
    return true;
}
```

Мой Loader:

```
 static class TrackLoader extends CursorLoader {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public TrackLoader(Context context,SQLiteDatabase db){
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }
    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        return Tracker.getAll(db);
    }
}
```

Методы LoaderCallbacks:

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("myTag", "Loader:onCreateLoader()");
    return new TrackLoader(this,db);

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    myAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    Log.d("myTag", "Loader:onLoaderFinished");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d("myTag", "Loader:onLoaderReset()");
}
```

UPDATE: Эта проблема только когда используется кастомный адаптер. Привожу код моего адаптера:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    Context context;
    Cursor c;
    int resorceID;
    List<Tracker> trackersList;
    ContentValues cv;
    int idx=0;
    int position,accessToIF=0;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public MyAdapter(Context context,int resourceID,Cursor c,String[] from,int[]to,int flags,List<Tracker> list){
        super(context,resourceID,c,from,to,flags);
        this.context=context;
        this.c=c;
        this.resorceID=resourceID;
        this.trackersList=list;
        elapsed=new ArrayList<Long>(trackersList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < trackersList.size(); i++) {
            elapsed.add(i,Long.valueOf(i));
        }
        cv =new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Tracker.COL_FINISH,1);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        TrackHolder holder=null;
        Log.d("myTag",""+elapsed.size());
        this.position=position;
        View row = convertView;
        final Tracker tracker = trackersList.get(position);
        final long[] lastPause = new long[1];
        final long limitTime = tracker.getLimitTime();
        final boolean type = tracker.isType();
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resorceID,parent,false);
            holder = new TrackHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
            holder.chronometer = (Chronometer)row.findViewById(R.id.row_chronometer);
            holder.limitTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limitTime);
            holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
            holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (TrackHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        if(!trackersList.isEmpty()) {
            holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
            holder.finish = tracker.isFinish()?1:0;
            if(holder.finish==1) {
                holder.limitTime.setText("task finished");
                holder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - tracker.getLimitTime());
                holder.start.setEnabled(false);
                holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                //lastPause.add(position,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                lastPause[0] = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            }
            else {
                holder.limitTime.setText(tracker.getLimitTime().toString());
                holder.start.setEnabled(true);
                holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                lastPause[0] = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            }
            final TrackHolder finalHolder = holder;
            holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("myTag", "Start was pressed");
                    finalHolder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-(lastPause[0]-finalHolder.chronometer.getBase()));
                    finalHolder.chronometer.start();
                    finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.start.setEnabled(false);
                    Log.d("myTag", "Start was pressed with getBase() = " + getTime(finalHolder.chronometer.getBase()));
                    accessToIF++;
                }
            });
            holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalHolder.chronometer.stop();
                    lastPause[0] = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    finalHolder.start.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
            holder.chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                    if(elapsed.size()>position) {
                        elapsed.set(position, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());

                        if (elapsed.get(position) > 5000) {
                            Log.d("myTag", "elapsedTime = " + getTime(elapsed.get(position))+"position "+position);
                            finalHolder.limitTime.setText("task changed");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень банально и стыдно было не заметить) В кастомный адаптер я передавал список моих моделей `List<Trackers> trackersList;`При нажатии на удалении нужно было удалять выбранный итем из этого списка `trackerList.remove(position);`

Comment: Не забываем отмечать ответ "принятый", даже если сам ответил, что он зря не болтался в списке неотвеченных.

Comment: пишет, что смогу принять свой ответ через 2 дня